# Get name of generic type T as String

Tags: swift, generics

Given a generic type such as the following, how can I get the type name of "T" as a string. I plan to use it for logging or possibly within the `String` key of a dictionary.

```
struct GenericStruct<T> {
    var value: T
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `T.self` in Swift 3

Within the generic type, get the name of type `T` by converting `T.self` or `type(of: T.self)` to a `String`. I found that `type(of:)` was not necessary but it's worth being aware of since in other cases it removes other details about the Type.

The following example demonstrates getting the name of the generic type `T` within a struct and a class. I also included code to get the name of the containing type.

### Example

```
struct GenericStruct<T> {
    var value: T

    var genericTypeDescription: String {
        return "Generic Type T: '\(T.self)'"
    }

    var typeDescription: String {
        // type(of:) is necessary to exclude the struct's properties from the string
        return "Type: '\(type(of: self))'"
    }
}

class GenericClass<T> {
    var value: T

    var genericTypeDescription: String {
        let typeName = String(describing: T.self) // use this to get the type name alone
        return "Generic Type T: '\(typeName)'"
    }

    var typeDescription: String {
        let typeName = String(describing: self) // use this to get the type name alone
        return "Type: '\(typeName)'"
    }

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

enum TestEnum {
    case value1
    case value2
    case value3
}

let intGenericStruct: GenericStruct<Int> = GenericStruct(value: 1)
print(intGenericStruct.typeDescription)
print(intGenericStruct.genericTypeDescription)

let enumGenericStruct: GenericStruct<TestEnum> = GenericStruct(value: .value2)
print(enumGenericStruct.typeDescription)
print(enumGenericStruct.genericTypeDescription)

let intGenericClass: GenericClass<Int> = GenericClass(value: 1)
print(intGenericClass.typeDescription)
print(intGenericClass.genericTypeDescription)

let enumGenericClass: GenericClass<TestEnum> = GenericClass(value: .value2)
print(enumGenericClass.typeDescription)
print(enumGenericClass.genericTypeDescription)
```

### Console Output

```
Type: 'GenericStruct<Int>'
Generic Type T: 'Int'

Type: 'GenericStruct<TestEnum>'
Generic Type T: 'TestEnum'

Type: 'GenericClass<Swift.Int>'
Generic Type T: 'Int'

Type: 'GenericClass<TestEnum>'
Generic Type T: 'TestEnum'
```